# After launching the application, only the first line of the script is getting executed. After first statement none of the statements works

Tags: angular, protractor

I am getting the below error.

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish
>   after 100 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an
>   Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details:
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
>       While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="password"])   Stack:
>       ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 100 seconds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNlv1.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAwjO.png)

I am able to open the chrome browser and able to launch the application. After launching the application, only the first line of the script is getting executed. ie. I am able to send keys to the username text box. After this my script is not getting executed.

Note:
1.   If I include element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('test'); as first line after launching the application, it will work.
2.  I have also tried all the locators still I am getting the same error.

I am able to locate all the elements in the page, the problem here is after browser.get(“”); statement, only first statement works. This first statement can be to locate username or password textbox. After first statement none of the statements works.

Test.e2e.js looks like the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c2lJ.png)

Protractor.config.js looks like the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odkN9.png)

Command which I used for Execution test Spec.
   I navigated to the location where my scripts are stored in my local machine. 
   Open the command prompt in the above location. Then I run the following command from the command-line:
npm run protractor
Note : I have written my scripts using Visual Studio professional 2017 (Version 15.4.5)

Comment: Shouldn't this line "Locator: By(css selector, *[id="password"])" be "Locator: By(css selector, [id*="password"])

Comment: Is the website you are testing against angular?

Comment: In my spec.ts file i am using  element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('test');         Yes my application is using Angular 2.

Comment: Could you share your config file?

Comment: Please click on "enter image description here" link. You will be able to see the screen shot of error, config file and test.e2e.js file

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your `protractor.conf.js` in the `onPrepare() {}` block the parameter that disable special protractor waiting that was created for Angular app.

```
// protractor.conf.js
...
onPreapare() {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
}
```

You could take a look at that function directly in [Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled)

Comment: I included onPreapare() {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
}                                                                                                                        statement in my protractor.config.js file. I am getting the same error as above :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in the page class if you are testing a non-Angular based website.

Comment: My application uses Angular2

Comment: `.ignoreSynchronization()` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

As already said below, you should use waitForAngularEnabled:

```
onPrepare() {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
}
```

But there is a typo in the answer from Oleksii: onPreapare is not onPrepare

Please fix it and you'll get it.